# How to find id which is string with semicolon

Tags: mysql

I want to find assigned jury id from the table.Problem is all that id are joint with semicolon
Here are the records.

```
id  jury_id
 1   2;4;6
```

I want to find jury_id=4. How can i find that record ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try something like SELECT jury_id from table WHERE jury_id LIKE %$the_jury_id% (see the mysql doku for more information)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`find_in_set()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
where find_in_set(?, replace(jury_id, ';', ',')) > 0
```

Replace the `?` with your target value.

Note that to use this function the search string must be a CSV, so you must replace the semicolons with commas.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways

1.

```
let say jury_id came as $ids;
$array=explode(',',$ids);
if(in_array('4',$array)
{
   echo "id is in there";
}
```

2.

```
let say jury_id came as $ids;
if(strpos($ids,'4')==true)
{
    echo "id is in there";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like what F. Muller said, you can try it like

```
SELECT id,jury_id from table WHERE jury_id LIKE %$the_jury_id%
```

Comment: This won't work if jury_id may have more than one digit

Answer (score 0):

First remark is that it is an absolutely terrible database design.

To answer the question, you should be able to solve your problem with the `LIKE` operator:

```
id LIKE '%;4;%' or id LIKE '4;%' or id LIKE '%;4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

`select * from tbl_name where jury_id like '%jury_id%'`

Comment: Won't work: if jury_id is "1;14" your query will match when your search for just 4, which is incorrect